# Remove first two entrys from subfolder reading php script

Tags: php, directory, subdirectory

i got a function which gets all subfolders from a specific directory and display subfolders in html output with php.It is working so far but now i have two entrys from the folder above which is diplayed as . and the second entry as .. how i have to modify my script?

```
<?php
$dir = "pictures/whatsapp/";

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

// Where to filter or delete the two entrys from folder . and .. ???

            echo '<a href="whatsapp/'.$file.'/" title="Whatsapp DP '.ucwords(str_replace("-"," ", $file)).' Images"><i class="ion-social-whatsapp-outline"></i>'.ucwords(str_replace("-"," ", $file)).'<i class="ion-record"></i></a>';
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply add to loop following line to skip om . and ..

```
if ($file == "." or $file == "..") continue;
```

Comment: please try the code yourself because its not working my friend sorry so i searched myself and found the right solution by the way thanks for your help i appreciate.